# Putting cursor in QLineEdit

Tags: python, pyqt4

I would like to put a cursor in a blank line edit box without having to click on it.

I looked through the Reference here 
http://ftp.ics.uci.edu/pub/centos0/ics-custom-build/BUILD/PyQt-x11-gpl-4.7.2/doc/html/qlineedit.html#selectionStart

I tried calling

```
QLineEdit.home(True)
```

But this did not select the lineEdit so to say.

here is a watered down version of the code

```
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui
import sys
import os
import os.path

class Ui_Form1(QtGui.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        QtGui.QWidget.__init__(self)
        self.setupUi(self)


    def setupUi(self, Form):
        #init stuff
        Form.setObjectName("Form")
        Form.resize(794, 538)
        self.gridLayout = QtGui.QGridLayout(Form)
        self.gridLayout.setObjectName("gridLayout")
        self.hLayout = QtGui.QHBoxLayout(Form)
        self.hLayout.setObjectName("hLayout")
        self.vLayout = QtGui.QVBoxLayout(Form)
        self.vLayout.setObjectName("vLayout")


        #label for information
        self.gridLayout.addLayout(self.hLayout, 0, 0)
        self.hLayout.addLayout(self.vLayout, 0)
        self.label = QtGui.QLabel(Form)
        self.label.setObjectName("label")

        #label pixmap
        self.label2 = QtGui.QLabel(Form)
        self.label2.setObjectName("label")

        #line edit
        self.lineEdit = QtGui.QLineEdit(Form)
        self.lineEdit.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.lineEdit, 3,0)

        self.list = QtGui.QListWidget(self)
        self.list.setObjectName("outlist")

        self.list.setMinimumHeight(150)
        self.vLayout.addWidget(self.list, 1)
        self.hLayout.addWidget(self.label, 1)
        self.vLayout.addWidget(self.label2, 0)
        #self.hLayout.addWidget(self.label2, 0)
        self.label2.setText('line edit')
        self.retranslateUi(Form)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(Form)


    def retranslateUi(self, Form):
        self.label.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.label.setText('Picture would go here')
        self.label2.setText('line edit')
        self.list.addItem('cursor will disappear when this is pressed')
        #press enter to update pic
        #self.lineEdit.returnPressed.connect(self.update_pic)

        #####sh



if __name__ == "__main__":
        app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
        ex = Ui_Form1()
        ex.show()
        sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: you can place a code that can be executed please, we call that a [mcve].

Comment: I see that the cursor appears in the QLineEdit, what is your problem?

Comment: Did you try to call `setFocus()` on your `QLineEdit` object ?

Comment: This is it! I have been looking for that for forever, thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
self.lineEdit.setFocus(QtCore.Qt.StrongFocus)
```

Answer (score 0):

In PyQt5:

`self.lineEdit.setFocus()`